# We we need to create two AAD Apps for front end and backend?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am implementing single sign on with Azure Active Directory. The front end is in Angular and back end is in .net core WebApi.

I saw and example that you have to create two AAd apps one for front end and one for back end why we have to create two apps?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you define two apps is so that you can acquire and use an access token with the API.
Without that, you could only use an Id token, which should not be used for authorization in an API.
An Id token is only meant for the client that triggered the login.
When calling an API, you should use an access token for that API.

Comment: If i create a single app for both front end and back end is there any problem. and if I create two apps for front end and back end how I establish link between two apps on AAD?

Comment: The link is established by defining some scopes (delegated permissions) in the API, and then requiring those permissions from the front-end app.

Comment: I am using oidc-client in angular app to get token, I got the token, when I try to verify the token in the back end the token validation failed. and I get the error as 

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Comment: the scopes I am asking for are "openid,email,profile"

Comment: Are you using the v2 endpoint? In that case you should also specify a scope for your API so that you get an access token back. You'll need to specify it in a format of <app-id-uri>/<scope> as shown here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11847#issuecomment-406202261

Comment: Thanks, it works so far, I can validate the token at Backend, phew but now the problem is token issue does not allow me to read the user profile.

the end point i am using is https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo 

if is use "openid,email,profile" to get a token I can read the profile. and if I use 

"api://.../scope openid" scope to get token I can not read the profile.

Comment: :) You can read the user profile from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` using a token for MS Graph API. Your API can use the on-behalf-of grant flow to get the token using the token it received: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: I have created two apps( frontend and backend) in office AD and configure the API permission and expose it correctly. So when i login to the UI it asked me to consent for API and it's works well. But when i login from different AD ( organizations ) it does not work and says you dont own the resource error. any reason for that?

Comment: @juunas using the ID token in one app registration scenario is not a necessity: if you expose a scope and grant it to the same app registration, you'll get a valid access token with the client ID of the app registration as audience, which you can pass to the back-end app